# finding and replacing multiple words in a file with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a file. I want to replace word : if "a" is there, replace "a" with "p" else replace "a" with "q". and save that file. How to do this using batch script?

Comment: Does it have to be batch? A small Python programm and a regEx might serve better. Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856009/win-batch-regexp-search-and-replace

Comment: **if "a" is there, replace "a" with "p" else replace "a" with "q"** -- can you please explain the "else" part? If a is there then it will be replaced with "p". how will "q" come into picture?

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
sed "y/a/p/" file.txt > newfile.txt
```